# Keeping some files uncompressed while using zip

Tags: android, command-line, zip, unzip

I am trying to create a zip file using the following command.

```
zip -r somefolder.apk . -n *.mp4*
```

The idea is to compress all the elements in the directory while keeping the files having `.mp4` extension as they are (not compressed) and included in the zip folder. How can I do that?

When I run this command, the zip file is created successfully, however, the `.mp4` files are compressed as I can see them by running `unzip -lv somefolder.apk`

```
Defl:N   202016  46% 12-30-1979 19:00 89b64dcb  res/raw/some_animation.mp4
```

As far as I know the `Defl:N` indicates that the file has been compressed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, my colleagues helped me to find that out! Posting it here as an answer hoping other developers may find it useful!

We do not have to add the `*` here. The following command should work just fine!

```
zip -r somefolder.apk . -n .mp4:.zip:.gzip
```